# How to categorizing by one column in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm studying about Gene programing by perl.
It is little difficult for me using Perl. I am sorry about i'm not good at English.

I want to categorize by one column in perl.

This is my file. And file name is  Annuum.v.2.1.gff3

```
PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  PROTEIN gene    909002  910083  .   +   .   ID=CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.1
PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  PROTEIN mRNA    909002  910083  .+ ID=TC.CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.1;Parent=CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.1

PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  PROTEIN exon    909002  909168  .   +   0   Parent=TC.CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.1
PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  PROTEIN CDS 909002  909168  .   + 0 Parent=TC.CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.1

PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  PROTEIN exon    909759  910083  .   +   1   Parent=TC.CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.1
PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  PROTEIN CDS 909759  910083  .   +   1   Parent=TC.CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.1

PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  ISGAP   gene    930723  931169  783 +   .   ID=CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.2
PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  ISGAP   mRNA    930723  931169  783 +   .   ID=TC.CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.2;Parent=CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.2

PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  ISGAP   exon    930723  931169  .   +   .   Parent=TC.CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.2

PGAv.1.6.scaffold1  ISGAP   CDS 930723  931169  .   +   .   Parent=TC.CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.2
```

I want to categorize by second column and i want to show the count number and ID.
Like this below.
I forgot sth. These are all genes.

```
PROTEIN number      CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.1, CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.3, ...

ISGAP   number          CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.2, CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.26, ...
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: can you show the complete output you want for your example input?

Comment: i'm sorry. i forgot sth. i use this code for selecting only genes.
 my $stOut = "3rd_3.txt";
open IN,"Annuum.v.2.1.20160825.gff3";
open OUT,'>'.$stOut;
for(;my $stLine = <IN>;)
{
  
   my @stSplit =split /\t/, $stLine;
   if($stSplit[2] eq "gene")
   {
      print OUT "$stLine";
   }
   
}

close IN;
close OUT;

Comment: And i want to get              Protein     Number     CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.1, CA.PGAv.1.6.scaffold1.3, ...... like this

Comment: Are there more than the two categories `PROTEIN` and `ISGAP`?

Comment: yes, there are two more categories. ABINITIO and PGA1.6

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

We can use an implicit loop and autosplit mode together with a hash of the categories and arrays for each category. This gives:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -anF\t
next unless /ID=([^;]*)\n/; # process only lines with only ID
$categories{$F[1]} = 1;     # remember category (field 1)
push @{$F[1]}, $1;          # add item to the category's array
END { for (keys %categories)
      { $number = @{$_};    # number of items in category
        print "$_\t$number\t", join(", ", @{$_}), $/
      }
    }
```